# Media queries css not overiding the properties of different pixel ratio, once it applies , once it wont?

Tags: css, html, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCoVF.png)I am applying css properties at different width pixels . Parent properties overriding the child width properties . Ex max-width 425px , max-width 375px. Once it applies , and works fine but later it doesn't work. In developer tool i find the strike to the css properties.

Comment: If your (non-media query) css rules are overriding your css rules within your media queries - then it's most probably because 1) their selectors are more specific or (if not :) 2) the media queries css rules precede the non media query css (in which case - they should be written after the regular css rules)

Answer (score 0):

The most common error is not paying attention to your styles cascading arrangement.

Meaning, the base requirement for this to work is You to have the following hierarchy:

```
/* base CSS styles */
html {
    font-size: 10px; // Generic style
}

@media (max-width: 425px) {
    /* css for 425px and below */
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
    /* css for 375px and below */
}
```

No matter if you are working in a single file, or using imports of some kind, ***your main styles always come first*** then your media queries must be stacking down from the highest width to the lowest.

Comment: I am following the above arrangement from the begining

Comment: Then you must have some cache stored. Have you tried a hard reset of the page?

Comment: I had disabled the cache .